# In a for loop my if statement doesnt produce what i want

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement

Hi guys so the following is happening when i try access the code, the first part is good because without having the handbag in inventory i want it to say you are carrying however if i have the handbag i want it to say you are carrying these items in your handbag but the below happens;

What now? 
get torch
ok

What now? 
list
You are carrying:
torch

What now? 
go stairs
It's dark in here!

What now? 
get handbag
ok

```
What now? 
list
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
torch
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
wallet
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
keys
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
ring
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
USB
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
mobile
You are carrying these items in your handbag:
handbag
```

and here is the code

```
public void listWhatYouHave()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (hasItem[6])
        {
           System.out.println("You are carrying these items in your handbag:");
           switch (i)
           {
                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("torch");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("wallet");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("keys");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("ring");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("USB");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("mobile");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("handbag");
                    break;
                default: 
                    System.out.println("invalid item!");
                    break;
           }
        }
        else if (hasItem[i])
        {
            System.out.println("You are carrying:");
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("torch");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("wallet");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("keys");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("ring");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("USB");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("mobile");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("handbag");
                    break;
                default: 
                    System.out.println("invalid item!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

can you help... thanks (this is java obviously)

sorry for benig vague... pretty much when i dont have the handbag i want it to list what im carrying by saying 'you are carrying' however if i pickup the handbag at a point when thats picked up... i want it to say 'you are carrying these items in your handbag' but currently it prints out you are carrying just once... but you are carrying these items in your handbag is printed in everyline... i only want it once.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want, but I presume that `if(hasItem[6])`should be `if(hasItem[i])`

Comment: @Andrew: Could you please try to refine your question?

Comment: Sorry guys i have edited the question added what i wanted in the end... i just want it to only print out 'You are carrying these items in your handbag' once instead of every line.. that is if i have (hasItem[6])

Answer (score 2):

Your `hasItem[6]` value is true then `if (hasItem[6])` condiion will always true. 
 Your else part wont get excuted

May be you need `if(hasItem[i])` instead of `if(hasItem[6])`

Comment: That wouldn't be enough since he wants to write out the items only the user has. The else part executes when the user doesn't have a handbag, the if part executes when they have, but it does not check whether the user has the item as well.

Comment: thats pretty much spot on what Daniel commented... i want the if statement to list what the user has... not everything they "could" have.

Comment: @Andrew: I also wrote an answer for you, did you have time to try that as well? :)

Comment: @Daniel: Yes your code half works... it stops the println coming up for all items... however it now just says you are carrying in your handbag ...item... and say if you have two items... it will print it out twice... so still need to stop it from printing multiples.

Comment: @Andrew: I modified my answer to what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in the first part of your condition you only check whether the user has the hadbag and you don't check the item. The first condition should be rewritten:

```
if(hasItem[6] && hasItem[i])
{
 ....
```

At the same time I would refactor out the inner swich because it is twice there in the code. And I would suggest to use enumerated types instead of integer constants.

EDIT:

In order to prevent it to print the 'You are carrying' line multiple times you should refactor it out from the for loop.

I would do it this way:

```
public void listWhatYouHave()
{
    if (hasItem[6])
    {
        System.out.println("You are carrying these items in your handbag:");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You are carrying these items:");
    } 

    listItems(hasItem);
}

void listItems(bool[] hasItem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
          if(hasItem[i])
          {
              switch(hasItem[i])
              {
                  // ... put your case here
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if you don't want to write out the handbag being carried in the handbag you can remove it from the switch case, since it is something you use for a different purpose.

Comment: I dont know if i did anything wrong... not sure what the listItems(hasItem); however doing this and compiling it, it just returns to me a list of all items...

Comment: @Andrew: yes, sorry i forgot to copy the condition around the switch, i just modified the code. my bad, copy paste error.